# How to autobuild forms in ASP MVC4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a site in ASP MVC4, razor view. I have a form to input some data into my database (using the entity framework), using classes.

At the moment, I have to create a new input for each now property that I add in my class, but I want an autobuilder that loops through the class and add an input automatically. How can I do that?

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LSMDB.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Poster { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public int Budget { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public int Boxoffice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

-- Jurgen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `@Html.EditorForModel()` to do this for you.